# sort first value (latest date time entry) in tuple in dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to display a dictionary according to the latest date time entry. my date time is in a tuple that is stored to a key and its the first value in the tuple.
*** this dictionary reads content from a text file so my dictionary = {}

```
{'xavier': ('2020-08-13 13:34:01', 'running'), 'alvin': ('2020-08-14 14:34:10', 'basketball')}
```

anyone knows how to display it such that the key and values under 'alvin' displays first since the date time entry is the latest. something like this:

```
alvin ('2020-08-14 14:34:10', 'basketball')
xavier ('2020-08-13 14:34:01', 'running')
```

Thanks much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find this useful

```
import json

file_data = ''
filepath = 'filepath' #your filepath
with open(filepath, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    file_data = f.read()
my_dictionary = json.loads(file_data) #string file data converted to dictionary in Python

new_sorted_data = sorted(my_dictionary.items(), key=lambda x:x[1][0], reverse=True)
for i in new_sorted_data:
    print(i[0], i[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
from datetime import datetime

dct = {'xavier': ('2020-08-13 13:34:01', 'running'), 'alvin': ('2020-08-14 14:34:10', 'basketball')}


def sorter(item):
    """ Returns a datetime object """
    return datetime.strptime(item[1][0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(sorted(dct.items(), key=sorter, reverse=True))
```

Comment: hi Jan! sorry i did not add this in but my dictionary actually reads content from a text file. so my dict = {}
do you know how to go about doing it? :)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, to work on a `list`-like structure, which you get from `dict.items()` and sort it with the help of the `sorted()` function.

An example:

```
d = {
    'xavier': ('2020-08-13 13:34:01', 'running'), 
    'alvin': ('2020-08-14 14:34:10', 'basketball'),
    'peter': ('2020-08-19 16:42:00', 'tennis')
}

sd = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0], reverse=True)

for item in sd:
    print(item)
# ('peter', ('2020-08-19 16:42:00', 'tennis'))
# ('alvin', ('2020-08-14 14:34:10', 'basketball'))
# ('xavier', ('2020-08-13 13:34:01', 'running'))
```

Explanations:

- The `key` argument is used to retrieve an object to run the comparison on, i.e. the example will work on the date string
- The sorting works even though you provide only string, as it is in the right format, it might not work correctly if you work on another form, e.g. `14.08.2020`. You can use the `datetime` library then.

Comment: As of `Python 3.5 (6?)` they actually do have an order.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6 It was 3.6

Comment: OK, but they are not ordered by any criteria based on it's content. They are ordered based on the insertions made. Thanks anyway. Good to know.

Comment: Well, if you use a comprehension based on some criteria then that's how the get inserted. Meaning: `dct = {key: value for key, value in sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])}` will actually follow a rule.

Comment: thanks for your input! sorry i did not add this in but my dictionary actually reads content from a text file. so my dict = { } do you know how to go about doing it? :)

Comment: That's another question, but possibly you read it with the `json` library. See @shreyaskars answer.

Answer (score 0):

`sorted` would be a choice.

```
from datetime import datetime

your_dict = {'xavier': ('2020-08-13 13:34:01', 'running'), 'alvin': ('2020-08-14 14:34:10', 'basketball')}
for k, v in sorted(your_dict.items(), key=lambda item: datetime.strptime(item[1][0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), reverse=True):
    print(k, v)
```